# My Ubuntu Live CD will only connect to my wired internet on one computer

Tags: internet, ethernet

I recently burned the Ubuntu 12.4.2 live cd, and put it in my Lenovo N580 notebook to install Ubuntu to my 32 GB Sandisk flash drive. It completed successfully, but after booting from my flash drive my computer would not connect to the internet via ethernet, or even recognize a physical conection. The computer's main operating system is Windows 8, and it will connect to my ethernet just fine. An idea occured to me, so I tried it. I put my Live CD into my Sony Vaio VPCEE41FX and booted from the live cd successfully, but on that computer it WOULD connect to my ethernet. I cleared Ubuntu off of my flash drive and thought about installing it on the Vaio since it could connect to the internet with my ethernet. If I did this, would that make the copy of the OS on my flash drive be able to connect to my home internet through ethernet on my Lenovo notebook? This is really frustrating, and is causing me a lot of greif. If anyone has had a similar isue and solved it, or if anyone knows how to help me, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: The difference is in the hardware, there's no reason for cross-install. The Vaio has a a different ethernet adapter than the Lenovo, the one is working out-of-the-box, the other does not, it needs some extra troubleshooting to work. I can help, but you need to run `lspci -nn`  and `lshw -C network` in a terminal and include their output in your post.

Comment: Thank you for your your quick response, and I apologize for my late reply. I ran those commands in my terminal and recorded the outputs, but copying them into this comment is too long by over 2000 characters, is there any way I could send it to you via a private message, or something like that? This is my first time using this website. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You posting time is totally fine. In this case please upload them to http://paste.ubuntu.com and just post the link here.

Comment: Here's the link
http://paste.ubuntu.com/5695777/

Answer (score 0):

There is no driver loaded for your wired ethernet adapter, however you can load it by executing:

`modprobe alx`

If it's working, tell the system to load this driver on every boot:

`echo alx >> /etc/modules`

The wireless adapter seems to have the appropriate driver loaded.

Comment: I entered the modprobe alx command, but the output was: "FATAL: Module alx not found"

Comment: The module is missing, that is the problem. Run this: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-generic`

Comment: should i run that from my live cd, or the OS saved on my flash drive? I'm the process of re-installing Ubuntu on my flash drive, so if I need to do it there It will be a few more minutes.

Comment: And should I be connected to my ethernet when I run that command? or will it not matter?

Comment: Yes, you need to run it on the installed system on the Lenovo. Doesn't matter the connection for the time loading the module. If it still doesn't work, I will get back to you in a few hours.

Comment: I ran that command, and this is the output:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package generic

I'm not sure what the last line meant, but I'm still unable to connect to my ethernet.

Comment: Are you sure that you have run the proper command? The package name is `linux-generic` not just `generic`. Have you tried `sudo modprobe alx` ? What does `uname -r` tell you?

Comment: I re-ran the command successfully, but even after doing that it still will not connect to my ethernet. There were several errors in the output in the terminal. For some reason that output was not saved to my clipboard for me to paste into a document to paste at paste.ubuntu.com, and I won't be able to access wireless internet again until tomorrow. But the output of uname -r is "3.5.0-23-generic".

Answer (score 0):

If you can plug the Lenovo in to a wired network, you can download and install the package providing the driver for your network card with

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.4-$(uname -r)
```

If you can't connect the Lenovo to a wired network, you can download the package from http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/admin/.  You need to choose the package that matches your kernel version.  Run `uname -r` in a terminal and find the package that ends in the same version number.